# Common function that is used both in `tests` and `src` not found

Tags: rust

I have a number of tests defined inside some of my modules with:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    ...
```

and a number of tests found inside my `/tests` directory. All of these happen to need a common function called `get_local()` that I have put inside a `utils` module

```
+src
 |-lib.rs
 |-utils.rs
 |-...
+tests
 |_common.rs
```

Now since this function is only used in case I run tests I thought I should add a `#[cfg(test)]` above it.

```
#[cfg(test)]
pub fn get_local() -> SomeResult { ... }
```

and then I make sure it is inside `lib.rs`:

```
pub mod utils;
```

When I try using the function in `tests/common.rs` though:

```
use my_crate::utils::get_local;
```

and run the tests with the `test` command I get the error: `no get_local in utils`. This error only goes away if I remove `#[cfg(test)]` from the declaration of `get_local`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

`#[cfg(test)]` is only active when *the crate is being compiled into a test binary* (instead of a library or normal binary) — the same condition under which `#[test]` functions are compiled to be run rather than ignored. But for a `tests/` test, the crate being compiled in test mode is *not your library* — it's a separate binary crate for the test, which Cargo sets up to *depend on* your library compiled normally.

Thus,  `tests/` tests may only test the "public API" of your library — they see it no differently than a dependent crate outside your library.

As a workaround, you can use `#[doc(hidden)]` instead of `#cfg(test)]` so that the function is always available but undocumented, or you can put it in a module which is compiled into the test as well as the main library (but it's tricky to write code that works in both cases).

Answer (score 1):

As for the "why does this happen?", Kevin Reid already answered: code in `tests/` are "Integration Tests" and, therefore, uses the regular version of your lib (not the test-compiled one). See [Integration Testing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/integration_testing.html).

You may use the approach bellow to have a common test module for a single crate. Note that, for Integration Tests, each file inside `tests/` is compiled as an individual crate. You may still create modules there.

With that said, my approach to having common test code is to put them inside a "test_commons" module and use:

lib.rs:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test_commons;
```

The contents of test_commons.rs has nothing special -- functions are defined without any #[cfg(test)] annotation.

Then, to use it:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use crate::test_commons::{self,ContainerKind,Blocking};
...
```

For Integration Tests inside `tests/` to share that same code, simply use:

```
#[path = "../../src/test_commons.rs"] mod test_commons;
```

Comment: I suggest `#[path = "../../src/test_commons.rs"] mod test_commons;` instead of `include!`. The advantage of this is that the included code is a separate module like normal files are, instead of inlined into the containing module, so it's less of a weird case.